# Unable to Download Application - "APP" could not be downloaded at this time

Tags: iphone, download, installation, icloud, testflight

I have a "PLUS" version of my app and the regular version.  I archive both of them using different targets.  I upload the ipa's to TestFlight (also to my Hockey server) and the "PLUS" version always downloads just fine.  But the regular version always give me the "Unable to Download Application" error.

I'm not changing the code at all between the two builds.  I do a "clean" in between builds.  The only difference in code is I define a "PLUS_VER" macro that changes some of the code.  And there are a few differences in resource files associated with the two targets.  This used to never happen, but this issue has been consistent across every time I've built with this current version.

Any ideas?

<><

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks for the tip on looking at the console.  While it was installing I saw that the provisioning profile didn't agree with the iCloud ubiquitous key-value store entitlement.  We're enabling iCloud with this release.

I went in and "edited" each provisioning profile (essentially doing nothing....) and re-downloaded them and it fixed the problem.

Kind of annoying that Apple doesn't invalidate your provisioning profile or let you know it needs updating at least... :-/

Answer (score 6):

I was battling with this same issue and this question is 2nd on google. The error basically means that there is a reason that the app cannot be installed. There are lots of different reasons this could be the case. The only way to find out is to look at the console while the app installs and a more useful error message will appear there.

If you have access to the machine you can use the organiser window in Xcode to see the console for an attached device. If you don't have access to the machine get the user to install the iPhone Configuration Utility. There are both Windows and Mac versions available to download from Apple. They can then see the console and email the output to you.

In my case I was using Testflight to install development builds. I thought there must be some provisioning issue and tried loads of different things. In the end when I saw the console output it was obvious that we were trying to install an iOS 6 app on an iOS 5 device.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems using OTA (useing XCode 4.3.3, i guess its the same in XCode 4.x.x).

It only let me install Apps on Development Devices when i use the Release Provisioning Profile. When i changed the setting in the Scheme (By klicking on the Schemename and selct "Edit Scheme...". On the left row, there are this scheme settings, where i had to click "Archive" and change the "Build Configuration" to "Debug"). Than i was able to distribut Apps using OTA with my Development Provisioning Profile.

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Check that the application bundle ID in the `Info.plist` matches the installation plist on the servers, that the installation URL point to the correct plist and the installation plist points to the correct IPA URL.

Comment: I've definitely checked and re-checked all the identifiers and URLs.  The App seems like it finishes downloading and then errors on the install step... but the error still just says "Unable to Download Application".  Regardless, it's not like TestFlight to get that stuff wrong.  So yea... seems like it's a different issue.

Comment: What does the console log say?  Is the provisioning profile in date and does it include the device UDID?

Comment: What console log?  Is there a console log while it's installing an app from the net?  Yea, the provisioning profile is in date and includes all the UDIDs....

Comment: Open the organiser window in Xcode, under each connected device, there's a *Console* entry where you can read the console log.

Answer (score 0):

I just had just problem, it seems testflight is down. It was not showing in the [system status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) from the beginning but they updated it to reflect the period I experienced the problem.

[image: testflight]

Answer (score 0):

As said in other answers, you'll need to check the Console to be sure.

As an example, i found the following error which is self-explanatory:

`The bundle being installed with bundle ID com.foo.myapp is authorized by a free provisioning profile, but apps validated by those are not allowed to be installed from this source`

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this is self-explanatory? I have an app, that I wrote, compiled, and that I can't run/debug on my own machine due to this error.

Comment: By 'this source' it means Hockey/testflight/downloaded. Eg free profiles only work when your phone is plugged into your laptop, uploaded direct from xcode.