# ios 9 : Unable to download '<app name>' at this time

Tags: ios9

I am able to run my application on `iPhone 6 iOS 9` , if I deploy it from `xcode` , Or if I put the `.ipa` of application in `Organizer->device`.

But if I download it from [Cick Here](http://itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://xxxx.plist), it is giving alert `Unable to download '<app name>'` at this time.

I checked the plist. bundle identifier is same as ipa.
What will be the solution?
For iOS 9 is their any other settings need to be done in plist?
What is the standard format of plist for iOS 9?

Comment: check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592975/unable-to-download-application-app-could-not-be-downloaded-at-this-time   or this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266418/unable-to-download-application-appname-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time

Comment: I tried downloading from http://www.diawi.com . it is working if I download from their link. Only giving problem for downloading from plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had similar issue earlier, solved it by updating the manifest plist file, i.e. plist file which contains url for ipa. 
Earlier I used to update only the URL for ipa in assets, but now apple we have to update the metadata as well. for example, 'bundle-version', 'bundle-identifier', 'title', 'subtitle' & 'kind'.

Key *kind* should always be *software*.

Comment: I changed budle identifier in my plist file  and then i was able to download the ipa.

Comment: Haha I thought you were doing a Yoda thing with "Kind should be software always." Perhaps some backticks (`kind`, `software`) might clarify that line!

Comment: now you can create your own manifest plist file(Xcode 7+), go to organizer and whilst exporting an ipa file, in the final screen there is an option 'include manifest over the air installation.' check that and voila, now you have your ipa plus your manifest plist.